# Is it possible to use woff2 fonts with PDFMake?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfmake

PDFMake states that it is possible to  [embed custom fonts at build time](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/fonts/custom-fonts-client-side/) for client side work.

However, the documentation makes no mention of what font file types are supported.

Eg:

```
pdfMake.fonts = {
    Roboto: {
        normal: 'Roboto-Light-Latin.woff2',
        bold: 'Roboto-Regular-Latin.woff2'
    },
}
```

When I embed woff2 files in my build process for `vfs_fonts.js`, I get `Uncaught RangeError: "value" argument is out of bounds`. This does not occur if I use TTF font versions.

```
Uncaught RangeError: "value" argument is out of bounds
    at checkInt (pdfmake.js:2298)
    at Uint8Array.writeUInt16BE (pdfmake.js:2373)
    at EncodeStream.<computed> [as writeUInt16BE] (pdfmake.js:51031)
    at NumberT.encode (pdfmake.js:6232)
    at ArrayT.encode (pdfmake.js:15995)
    at VersionedStruct.encode (pdfmake.js:54300)
    at Struct.encode (pdfmake.js:16134)
    at TTFSubset.encode (pdfmake.js:49346)
    at pdfmake.js:49039
    at Item.run (pdfmake.js:4314)
```

Is it the case I have something wrong in my config/font files, or does PDFMake not support woff2?

Answer (score 1):

I believe pdf format does not support woff2 format, as woff2 is specifically made for web browser usage. Here are links as proof -

Ref[1] - Woff2 support by browser - https://caniuse.com/woff2

Ref[2] - Faq from a font website -
[https://www.fontsmith.com/faqs/70#:~:text=Note%3A%20You%20can%20only%20embed,and%20WOFF2%20cannot%20be%20embedded](https://www.fontsmith.com/faqs/70#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20You%20can%20only%20embed,and%20WOFF2%20cannot%20be%20embedded).